using streams for voice assistant and graphical window
when I connect the streams so that the graphical window and the voice assistant work simultaneously, I get an error message that the main file does not see the file where my data_set is located (that's where I train my voice assistant). when I remove the streams in the function file, the code works. but it only executes threads in the Main file at the same time
here is the Main file code:
import queue 
import sounddevice as sd 
import vosk
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer 
import json 
import cv2 
import threading

import words
from skills import *

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


q = queue.Queue() 

model = vosk.Model('vosk-model-small-ru-0.22') 

device = sd.default.device 
samplerate = int(sd.query_devices(device[0], 'input')['default_samplerate']) 

def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    
    q.put(bytes(indata))

def recognize(data, vectorizer, clf):
    
    trg = words.TRIGGERS.intersection(data.split())
    if not trg:
        return


    data.replace(list(trg)[0], '')

    text_vector = vectorizer.transform([data]).toarray()[0] 
    answer = clf.predict([text_vector])[0] 

    func_name = answer.split()[0] 

    speaker(answer.replace(func_name, '')) 
    exec(func_name + '()') 

def cv2_voice():
    image = cv2.imread('1.png')
    cv2.imshow('image window', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def main():
   
   
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(words.data_set.keys()))

    clf = LogisticRegression()
    clf.fit(vectors, list(words.data_set.values()))

    del words.data_set

    
    with sd.RawInputStream(samplerate=samplerate, blocksize=16000, device=device[0],
                           dtype="int16", channels=1, callback=callback):  

        rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate) #
        while True: 
            data = q.get()
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                data = json.loads(rec.Result())['text'] 
                recognize(data, vectorizer, clf)

voice_thread = threading.Thread(target=main) 
cv2_thread = threading.Thread(target=cv2_voice)

voice_thread.start()  
cv2_thread.start()  


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()

tell me what I'm doing wrong. maybe there is another way or to improve this one?
I also provide a file with my functions for the assistant:
import os, sys, requests, subprocess
import pyttsx3
import time
import cv2
import random
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time


def rezult1():
    vo1 = threading.Thread(target=passive) 
    c1 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_1)
    vo1.start()  
    c1.start()   
   
def rezult2():
    vo2 = threading.Thread(target=weather)
    c2 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_2)
    vo2.start()
    c2.start()
 

def rezult3():
    vo3 = threading.Thread(target=offBot)
    c3 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_2)
    vo3.start()
    c3.start()
    
def rezult4():
    vo4 = threading.Thread(target=passive)
    c4 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_3)
    vo4.start()
    c4.start()

    

def rezult5():
    vo5 = threading.Thread(target=passive)
    c5 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_4)
    vo5.start()
    c5.start()
   

def rezult6():
    vo6 = threading.Thread(target=smex)
    c6 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_2)
    vo6.start()
    c6.start()
   

def rezult7():
    vo7 = threading.Thread(target=passive)
    c7 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_2)
    vo7.start()
    c7.start()

    
def rezult8():
    vo8 = threading.Thread(target = TimerVoice)
    c8 = threading.Thread(target = emotion_2)
    vo8.start()
    c8.start()

   
def rezult9():
    vo9 = threading.Thread(target=vremia)
    c9 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_2)
    vo9.start()
    c9.start()

def rezult10():
    vo10 = threading.Thread(target=calc)
    c10 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_3)
    vo10.start()
    c10.start()
def emotion_2():
    images = ['1.png', '7.png', '2.png'] 

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img) 
        cv2.waitKey(1000) 

    cv2.waitKey(0) 

def emotion_1(): 
    images = ['1.png', '2.png', '4.png']

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)  

    cv2.waitKey(0)

def emotion_3(): 
    images = ['1.png', '6.png']

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)  

    cv2.waitKey(0)

def emotion_4():
    images = ['1.png', '8.png', '9.png', '10.png']

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)  

    cv2.waitKey(0)

def emotion_5():
    images = ['1.png', '8.png', '3.png']

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000) 

    cv2.waitKey(0)

def emotion_6(): 
    images = ['1.png', '5.png']

    for image_path in images:
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.imshow('Image', img)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)  

    cv2.waitKey(0)



engine = pyttsx3.init() 
engine.setProperty('rate', 180) 

def speaker(text):
    engine.say(text) 
    engine.runAndWait() 


def weather():
    try: #цикл try
        params = {'q': 'London', 'units': 'metric', 'lang': 'ru', 'appid': ''} 
        response = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', params=params) 
        if not response: 
            raise
        w = response.json() 
        speaker(f" {w['weather'][0]['description']} {round(w['main']['temp'])} ") 
    except: 
        speaker('error')


def passive():
    pass 

def offBot():
    sys.exit() 

def smex():
    pass


class TimerVoice():
  
    def parse_command(text):
        
        words = text.split() 
        if len(words) >= 5 and words[0] in ["Put it down", "get it started"] and words[1] == "timer" and words[
            2] == "on": 
            try: 
                minutes = int(words[3]) 
                word_minutes = words[4] 
                if word_minutes in ["minute", "minutes"]: 
                    return minutes, word_minutes 
            except ValueError:
                pass 
        return None, None 

    
    def set_timer(minutes, word_minutes):
        
        seconds = minutes * 60 
        time.sleep(seconds) 
        speaker(f"{minutes} {word_minutes}.") 



def vremia():
    curr_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime())
    speaker(f" {curr_time}")

I tried using streams in two files. I tried it in the main file. but it is unsuccessful. I expect my assistant and the cv2 graphics window to work at the same time
